# HoloEverywhere edittext not working and not appearing as it should

Tags: android, android-edittext, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using HoloEverywhere edittext in my project.

```
    <com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.EditTextHolo 
            android:id="@+id/etmembname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Its not working as it should.
I'm unable to type anything in it.
I'm not even getting a cursor when clicking it.

But, when i use the arrow keys in the keyboard, i am able to see a cursor at the beggining
of edittextholo but unable to type anything.

Moreover, it's not appearing the way it is meant to be.
like in the default ICS edittext, i'm unable to see the blue underline in the edittextholo.

Moreover, when i click the "graphical layout" tab in eclipse, i'm getting this warning like thing.

**The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Typeface.createFromAsset() is not supported.(Ignore for this session)**

Is there anything wrong in my imports or in my usage?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is this issue which is the cause so either update HoloEverywhere to the newest release or pluck out the new version of EditTextHolo from the source

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/40